# MongoDb and expressJS trying to undertand Code

Tags: mongodb, express, web

```
  function _allUsers(callback){
     var db = connect.get();

    db.collection("users").find({}).toArray(function(err,data){
      if(err){
        callback(err);
    }else{
        callback(null,data);
    }
 });
}
```

I am trying to understand this code, I have been looking around the web but I find the explanations kinda defficult to understand ( I am new at Mean stack), so my questions are:

1. What does the Collection method do? I am not sure but the string "users" is it just the name of our collection with all users?
2. Why do we have to use a callback in this situation? (I find callbacks very confusing).
3. And why do we have to give toArray function, an annonymous function?
4. Instead of toArray could I use pretty method() without any annonymous function as a parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MEAN Stack is a software bundle of software programs supporting applications written in all javascript. This means you can use javascript from your database, to your back-end and front-end.

MEAN actually stands for the first characters of each software program included in the stack. **M**ongoDB, **E**xpressjs, **A**ngularJS and **N**odeJS.

**1**

MongoDB is a NoSQL database which uses BSON (similar to JSON) to store so called `documents`. Look at a document as if it is a single entity or row in a traditional database. These entities (or rows) are stored in `collections` (a collection of documents) which can be compared to tables.

So the answer to your 1st question is opens up the `users` collection, which grants access to all the user documents.

**2**

NodeJS is asynchronous by design. This allows NodeJS to perform a lot of operations while running on a single thread*. Because NodeJS is single-threaded we need a way to write our code `non-blocking` meaning we can start an operation, proceed with executing other code and come back whenever that operation is finished.

In your case we request access to the `users` collection, this takes some time. In order to allow other parts of our application to continue processing we use a callback. When we have access to our collection, our callback is executed and we can perform whatever operation we wanted to do when we first requested access.

*NodeJS actually runs on multiple threads but a developer never has to worry about multithreading, NodeJS does that for us.'

**3**

This is exactly what the previous point is about.

> The `.toArray()` method returns an array that contains all the documents from a cursor. The method iterates completely the cursor, loading all the documents into RAM and exhausting the cursor. [Source](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/)

`.toArray()` is a computionally intensive operation. Since we do not want to wait untill `.toArray()` is finished but proceed processing the rest of our code, we give it a `callback` so that we can come back to our collection processing whenever it's ready.

**4**

From what I can read from the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/) I guess you could indeed write *blocking code* and do it this way:

`var users = db.collection("users").find({}).toArray();`

This however will block your code entirely. There is never a good reason to do this.

Disclaimer: I left out or oversimplified details in this explanation for ease of understanding.

Comment: This is a REALLY REALLY good answer! Thank you! But then how do I know when to use these callbacks? I understans if there something that can take time, i should use them, but is there a good rule when to use them? The way you just explained it, I can conclude that using callbacks when working with files or databases could be very fundamental.

Comment: When writing your own software it's often good to ask yourself how intensive the operation you're doing is. If you're just adding 2 numbers, a callback won't improve performance (it might actually be worse due to overhead), if you are however saving a user to a database or writing to a file, a callback is essential. It's a gut feeling really but I'm sure you'll get the hang of it. Lucky you, any NPM modules you find and probably will use support callbacks, so you're required to use those. So it's extremely likely you're already doing callbacks when doing database and file operations.

Comment: Thank you for your time.

Comment: I was wondering why are we using callback in this case: callback(err) and callback(data) ? I cant really make sence of it with what that has been explained in above.

Comment: Good question. It's an unspoken rule in NodeJS to place any errors as the first parameter in the callback function `callback(err, data);`. This way the placement of an error, if any occur, is always consistent, regardless of the function or library/module you're using. If no errors occur, `null` is passed in stead of an error `callback(null, data);`. This way you can check for any errors by doing `if (err) {}` (if `err` is `null` this comparison will return `false`, otherwise `true`.

Comment: I see thank you. What do you mean by: " This way the placement of an error, if any occur, is always consistent, regardless of the function or library/module you're using. "

Comment: By always putting the error (`err`) object as the first parameter of any callback, since it's a design rule of NodeJS, you never need to look where the error parameter is. So whether or not an error occured, the first parameter will always be an error object. Even if no error occurs, the first parameter will still be the error object, it will simply hold the value `null`. It's just a language wide consistency.

Comment: Ahhhh that makes sence.

Answer (score 0):

1. `db.collection('users')` this will return the users [collection](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html) instance
2. we are using callback for asynchronous
3. the annonymous function in `toArray` is its callback
4. this is dependent on the library in use..

> without any annonymous function as a parameter

expressjs is an asynchronous programming, we need callback || Promises

Comment: you are not getting any likes for that answer, it seems you are as confused as I am!

Answer (score 0):

You can think of the collection as of table in MySQL. A collection consists of documents (rows/items/records in MySQL). Your example calls the `Users` collection and finds all documents (records) in it.
About the callbacks - NodeJS/Express are commonly callbacks-oriented. This is the pattern they use and most of the code is using it, because it is `asynchronous`. If you need to be sure that some snippet is executed right after some other snippet, you have to use callback (or promise).
Calling toArray() depends on what your callback expects. You can skip calling this method if the callback expects the [Query](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query-js) object returned by the `find()` method. All that depends on your callback.
You can use non-anonymous function, too, but you have to have in mind the `asynchronous` logic and continue using callbacks/promises. You can read more about callbacks and promises in [this](https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-difference-between-a-promise-and-a-callback-in-Javascript) Quora's article.
[Here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-find) you can find more about the `find()` method.